# Is there a JavaScript framework for context-aware popups?

Tags: javascript, popup, mobile-website, javascript-framework, popover

I'm looking for something like [Add2Home.js](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen):

[image: Add2Home.js]

but much more generic and customizable:

- I would like to inform the user e.g. "Did you know you can click this button to do this?"
- The popup should point to specific UI elements on the page.
- The framework should store a cookie whether a certain popup has been displayed (possibly also if it has been clicked away by the user).
- It should work and look good on mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an **[opentip](http://www.opentip.org/)** javascript tooltip framework.

I don't think it's stores cookies, but has a lot of different popups styles and worked well for me on mobile devices.

Comment: Awesome, that's a great starting point for me. Thanks!